# How can I loop through all sub folder of FolderA and execute a command do check modified files

Tags: windows, batch-file, cvs

I have a cvs client through which I can get list of modified files within a directory. 
For example:

```
My workspace(Top folder) -" D/MyWorkspace"

My Project A(Sub Folder) - D/MyWorkspcace/AProject
```

There are other projects in the same folder Like D/MyWorkspcace/BProject,D/MyWorkspcace/CProject and so on.

What I am doing currently that open command prompt, use cvs login command which prompt me for a password and on login. I go to each directory one by one and use command like

`"D:\MyWorkspcace\AProject> cvs -q diff --brief c"` (In command prompt)

which will provide me list of modified files in current directory.

In this way I repeat it for my 5 projects to get the list of modified files in all projects.

Is there a way to create a `.bat` file which loop through all the sub folders of MyWorkspcace which do not starts with a "." and execute above command for each of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /d /r %%d in (*.*) do (
    set folder=%%~nxd
    set first=!folder:~0,1!
    if not !first! == . (
        pushd "%%d"
        cvs -q diff --brief c
        popd
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

@Berend thanks mate it worked

cvs -d :pserver:CSCHOSTING\ytyagi2@blahblah-pd-deploy2:/blahblah/repository login
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /d /r %%d in (*.*) do (
    set folder=%%~nxd
    set first=!folder:~0,1!
    if not !first! == . (
        pushd "%%d"
        cvs -q diff --brief
        popd
    )
)

Just used login command at first which prompts for password and removed "c" before popd. I don't know much about it so can't say. But yes it worked fine. Can i record output to a text file stored on same path as .bat file.

Comment: Sure, change the cvs command so it pipes it output to a file, e.g.

    cvs -q blahblah > c:\temp\output.txt